# Connecting to SAP Open Hub through Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, saprfc

I'm working with a client to ETL data from SAP into an Azure storage account. Here are my current conditions:

1) The Open Hub destination has not been set up.

2) We're using Azure Data Factory to ETL data.

3) I can connect to SAP using the SAP Table connector, however, I'm getting an RFC error when I go to select the data source. The specific error is Failed to invoke function /SAPDS/RFC_READ_TABLE2.

Specifically focusing on #1 above, is it possible to successfully connect to SAP using the Azure Data Factory SAP Open Hub connector even if an Open Hub destination does not exist? i.e. is there a configuration setting that needs to be performed for access to connect?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome,would you please mark this answer for others' reference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to successfully connect to SAP using the Azure Data
>   Factory SAP Open Hub connector even if an Open Hub destination does
>   not exist?

The short answer is no. Based on the ADF for SAP [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-business-warehouse-open-hub#dataset-properties),the open hub destination name is `required` property:

[image]

More details about ADF's overall support on SAP data integration scenario,please refer to this link:https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/master/whitepaper/SAP%20Data%20Integration%20using%20Azure%20Data%20Factory.pdf